# Use hc_tooltip in R Highchart to give format to different lines

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to format two series of my graph in highchart. The first graph is a serie and the another is a %change. So I want to format each serie using "hc_tooltip" argument. A simplified version of my code to show my problem is the next:

```
a <- c(30, 40, 10, 40, 80)
b <- c(3, 4, -1, -4, -8)
d<-cbind(a,b)
dt <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-05"), by = "days")

ts <- xts(d, dt )



highchart(type="stock") %>%
  hc_add_series(ts$a,
                type = "line",
                color="black") %>%
  
  hc_add_series(ts$b,
                type = "lollipop",
                color="red") %>%

  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = '<b>{point.a.name}</b>
                             {point.y.a:.4f}')%>%
  
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = '<b>{point.b.name}</b>
                             {point.y.b:.4f}%')
```

Like I hoped, It's not working. I want I can see the data from the first serie like integer and the second like % in the graph when I put the mouse in the serie. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to use the `tooltip.formatter` with the relevant function

**Example:**

```
 hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function () {
       if (this.series.name === "A") {
        return `<b>${this.series.name}</b></br>${this.y}`
      } else if (this.series.name === "B") {
        return `<b>${this.series.name}</b></br>${this.y}%`
      }}")
```

**JS Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zqyp85ag/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter